# Am I correct on this Statement?

Tags: java, primitive-types

Is it correct that there are predefined Class object representing all the 8 primitive types and void??

please tell whether I am correct or wrong?

Comment: Is this a quiz?  If so, what are the prizes?

Comment: no its not,was just confused so asked :P

Comment: but you can get a +1 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's true: there are `int.class,` `short.class`, etc, which are also given by `Integer.TYPE,` `Short.TYPE,` etc respectively. Even `void.class.`

Not, contrary to some other answers, to be confused with the *wrapper* classes `Integer, Short, ...` themselves.